# What is use of String args[] in Java?

Tags: java

I want to know that why do we use String args[] because I am a beginner and I am not able to understand why do we use it.

Comment: As a short answer, sometimes when we want to start our application we need to pass some arguments to it like `java -jar application.jar verbose root`, and then you get the arguments `verbose` and `root` and within your application judge what to do. You can google it there are more information out there.

Comment: As an aside `String args[]` is C style syntax. The recommended Java syntax is `String[] args` or `String... args`.

Answer (score 1):

These are the parameters which you pass to your program when running it.

For example, you can run `java MyProgram -param -verbose -enableSomething -key=value`

All these `-param`, `-verbose`, etc are those arguments.

See docs: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/cmdLineArgs.html